# select option in a dynamically loaded select box

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html-select, webmethod

I have two select boxes:

```
  <select id="ddlLanguage">
        </select>
        <select id="ddlLanguage2">
            <option value="C#">C#</option>
            <option value="Java">Java</option>
            <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
             <option value="VB.NET">VB.NET</option>
            <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
            <option value="jQuery">jQuery</option>
        </select>
```

I have this webmethod to load the first select box

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetLanguageList",
                data: '',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#ddlLanguage").empty().append($("<option></option>").val("[-]").html("Please select"));
                    $.each(msg.d, function() {
                        $("#ddlLanguage").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                    });
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("An error has occurred during processing your request.");
                }
            });

             $('#ddlLanguage').val('PHP');
        $('#ddlLanguage2').val('PHP');

        });
</script>
```

And here the webmethod:

```
[WebMethod()]
    public static ArrayList GetLanguageList()
    {
        ArrayList lstArrLanguage = new ArrayList();
        lstArrLanguage.Add(new ListItem("C#", "C#"));
        lstArrLanguage.Add(new ListItem("Java", "Java"));
        lstArrLanguage.Add(new ListItem("PHP", "PHP"));
        lstArrLanguage.Add(new ListItem("VB.NET", "VB.NET"));
        lstArrLanguage.Add(new ListItem("JavaScript", "JavaScript"));
        lstArrLanguage.Add(new ListItem("jQuery", "jQuery"));
        return lstArrLanguage;
    }
```

As you can see before document ready finish, I do this:

```
   $('#ddlLanguage').val('PHP');
            $('#ddlLanguage2').val('PHP');
```

But, It is only working for the second one, the one which is not loading from webmethod.

Comment: 'impossible' is not a good description of a problem. How are you trying to do this, and what is failing/not working?

Comment: For example: 
`$('#s2_combo').val('avalue');`

Comment: are you sure that values exists in option

Comment: For example in this example: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/04/how-to-populate-aspnet-dropdownlist.html
If I add after ajax call this code: `$('#ddlLanguage').val('PHP');` 
It is not working

Comment: where are you calling ``.val()``

Comment: In the aspx, in the document ready, after the ajax:

Comment: @Za7pi, can you post the whole code then? DDL initialization and the `val` call?

Comment: You can download the code from the ,link above. Then, add `$('#ddlLanguage').val('PHP');` after the ajax call.

Comment: If I put this code, but with a select not constructed by a webmethod, it is working perfectly. The problem is the load by a webmwthod.

Comment: @Za7pi, hopefully by now you have realized that it would be much easier to post the whole code, with this not working line, from the very start. Nevertheless,I'll try to guess. Does your code look like this: `$.ajax({/*optionshere*/}); $('#s2_combo').val('avalue');`

Comment: I have edited my question with all the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `val` is called before drop down is initialized with new values. Note that `ajax` by default performs asynchronous requests, which means that right after `ajax` is not guaranteed to finish its work. In fact it most likely won't! So when you are calling `val` right after `ajax` dropdown is still empty, and there is no value to select.

To fix this, either turn `ajax` in synchronous call with corresponding setting:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    ...
```

Or call `val` in success function, when everything is loaded for sure:

```
success: function(msg) {
    $("#ddlLanguage").empty().append($("<option></option>").val("[-]").html("Please select"));
    $.each(msg.d, function() {
        $("#ddlLanguage").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
    });

    $('#s2_combo').val('avalue');
},
```

Second option if a preferred one though.